# Admin Panel not working

Tags: magento-1.9

I have installed Magento 1.9. when I try to login to the Magento admin panel, I typed username and password, clicked Login button and nothing happens. No error or any other messages.

If I entered wrong username or password, It shows error.

Comment: Are you trying on chrome ? its due to cache change your browser it will work on new one.

Comment: I tried, but its not work

Comment: check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159420/magento-admin-panel-not-login-using-chrome-but-working-fine-in-firefox

Comment: Try from different browser than you used for installation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a multitude of reasons to why this happens I would recommend you take a look at Ashely Schroder  articel on this issue

http://www.aschroder.com/2009/05/fixing-magento-login-problem-after-a-fresh-installation/

**Possible causes could be:**

1. Domain Name with no dots
2. Timezone differences between server and client
3. Cookie domain does not match server domain
4. Multiple Valid Cookies

My Non recommended solution if you absolutely have to fix it and cant find the root cause would be to

**Please make a back up before you edit these files**

open /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php

search for

```
$this->getCookie()->getDomain(),
$this->getCookie()->isSecure(),
$this->getCookie()->getHttponly()
```

and comment out  the above lines.